# Add m2m-through relation from two different classes to the same model

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have an existing applicaton where I have to change a regular `m2m` relationship to a through relation.
I need the ability to add extra parameters to the relation.
My problem is that I need to do it in two places.

This is the standard through example.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

I have another model that needs a `m2m` relation to Membership. My suggestion is the following.

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True)
    another_group = models.ForeignKey(AnotherGroup, null=True, blank=True)

class AnotherGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
```

It bugs me that I have to have one field that is null for every instance, or is this my only option?

Comment: Is this a real example? Group and AnotherGroup are equal, maybe you could distinguish them with an option field. Will adding a `kind = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=(('a', 'Kind A'), ('b', 'Kind B')))`work for you?

Comment: It is a real example. AnotherGroup and Group share some properties but not all. And they also have the same behavior with shared managers etc.

Comment: Maybe consider making them subclass a common base class (e.g. a model `AbstractGroup`) and define `Membership` as a m2n between `Person` and `AbstractGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using content type in through table.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```